This code keeps freezing unity whenever I test it and I can't figure out why
I'm trying to figure out why this specific code snippet appears to cause unity to freeze completely, to the point where I have to fully restart unity. I'm using System, System.Collections, System.Collections.Generic, and UnityEngine if that helps. I genuinely can't figure out the problem here.

        while (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            Instantiate(projectilePrefab, transform.position, projectilePrefab.transform.rotation);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(fireRate);
        }

This is the code that appears to be the problem, if I run it without this code it works fine. It's supposed to make a new projectile, wait a short time, then repeat as long as I hold the button down, but instead unity just freezes and does nothing.

if this is in update, you do not want a while.. you want an if... and a countdown.. otherwise no frames will happen until the button is stopped.and the sleep has completed.

@BugFinder .. and as the thread is frozen and then continues to execute this while loop the condition will never ever have the chance to become false again .. that infinite loop is the main issue causing the general freeze

Remove the Thread.Sleep. Most things in Unity run off of the main thread. You calling sleep on the main thread is not the way to do it. Not to mention you can emulate that sleep by using the firerate on the while condition.Otherwise put it in a Coroutine and use yield return new WaitForSeconds or sth along those lines.
Finally, look into object pools. You spam the Instantiate so much on Update (assuming) with your left mouse button pressed for a few frames and it's bound to cause a big spike. Instantiate is a slow path, which is why we tend to use Object Pools and pay that price early on and have preallocated instances that get reused.

Still not solving the issue of an infinite loop though ;)

That's true. I missed that. Although, It's not infinite. GetButton returns true only when pressed. So when it's not, it's a false and the while exits. It might seem like an infinite loop because of the spikes in perf.

...it's false and the while exits, provided you remove the seriously unnecessary Thread.Sleep and use the object pool, which removes the big spikes so there's no carry over from previous fires.

It will remain true forever.. with or without the sleep.. it stays true for the entire frame .. and the while loop never allows the frame to end

Oh I see. Because it's in the same frame already. You're right.
